# Crystal Report: Comparing 2 Years item performance based on QTY sold

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to crystal.
I have to show the top 217 items based on the quantities shipped in 2014 and side by side 2013.
Is there way to put in one report the data.

Item1 in 2103 may not be the same as 2014.
I get the data from invoice history detail table, and add the qty shipped from all item and then sort the top 217 items on basis of the sum.

I can have them in 2 reports or the previous year data from sub-report,but then the sub report data will appear as row after the current year.  however how can I put them in 1 report side by side for a better comparison.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Sweta - you'll get a better response if you can find a way to phrase this question so it doesn't sound like you are asking for someone to write the entire report for you, just to give you a hint as to where to get started. It might also help if you can indicate if you have programming/database experience, so those answering can judge where to start.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I am new to Programming as well as my first question on stackoverflow. I will take care next time.

Comment: no problem, this is a great forum, but sometimes new users get treated harshly, I just wanted to give a little advice before that happened! I hope that you have good experiences and stick with StackOverflow. Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

- Create a report that does what you want for a single year (say 2013)--you'll probably want to use a `top-N` grouping.
- Create a second report, without a datasource
- import the first report into the second one (call it 'year N-1'); don't link the sub-report to the main
- import the first report into the second report a second time (call it 'year N'); don't link the sub-report to the main
- edit the second sub-report and set the date to 2014

If you want the report to be more flexible, create a parameter in the main report (named 'year').  Link this parameter to each of the sub-reports, changing the respective, record-selection formulas to use the value to calculate the correct date ranges.

Comment: Thank you Craig. It gave me a different direction altogether than what I was thinking. I will work on it. A great   learning experience.